# How to prove a problem is #P-complete?

Tags: proof-writing, computational-complexity

What are the major steps in proving a problem is #P-complete?

For example, I know that showing a problem is NP-complete requires (i) showing the problem is in NP by giving a polytime verification algorithm, (ii) showing an existing NP-hard problem is polytime reducible to the given problem.

What would be the corresponding steps for a #P-completeness proof? Any resources would be helpful.

From Wikipedia I have: "By definition, a problem is #P-complete if and only if it is in #P, and every problem in #P can be reduced to it by a polynomial-time counting reduction..."

What makes a problem be in #P? Would reducing an exiting #P-complete problem to a given problem be enough?

Comment: Have you seen [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-complete)? A good account is in Chapter 13 of [Moore and Mertens](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Nature_of_Computation.html?id=jnGKbpMV8xoC).

Comment: Yes, I have, and updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, a polynomial-time *counting* reduction of a known #P-complete problem is enough.

Comment: Okay, so if there exists a #P-complete problem P1, and I reduce it to P2 in polytime, then P2 is also #P-complete? What is counting reduction -- making sure counting solutions for P2 is same as counting solutions for P1?

Comment: As long as your reduction allows you to retrieve the number of solutions to the instance of P2 from the number of solutions to the instance of P1.  If the number of solutions remains the same, your counting reduction is said to be *parsimonious*.

Comment: Did I correctly read your first sentence? "As long as your reduction allows you to retrieve the number of solutions to the instance of P2 from the number of solutions to the instance of P1." Shouldn't it be the otherway round, given I am reducing a known #P-complete problem P1 to a potentially new #P-complete problem P2?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it should be the other way around: you solve P1 directly and deduce the solution to P2.

Comment: Again, I guess you meant, "Yes, sorry, it should be the other way around: you solve P2 directly and deduce the solution to P1."

Comment: Consider adding an answer, so this question can be officially solved?

Comment: Sigh... Of course!  Maybe I should turn in instead of writing up an answer, but I'll try.

Comment: Alright, do it later!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good treatment of the complexity of counting problems may be found in [Moore and Mertens](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Nature_of_Computation.html?id=jnGKbpMV8xoC) and [Arora and Barak](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/computer-science/algorithmics-complexity-computer-algebra-and-computational-g/computational-complexity-modern-approach?format=HB&isbn=9780521424264).  In summary, the common approach to proving #P-completeness is through reduction.  Given a known #P-complete problem $P_1$, if we can find an appropriate reduction of $P_1$ to $P_2$, then $P_2$ is also #P-complete.

First, appropriate means that the reduction allows us to efficiently retrieve the number of solutions to $P_1$ from the number of solutions to $P_2$.  We call such a reduction *counting* and, specifically, *parsimonious* if it leaves the number of solutions unchanged.

Second, as in proving NP-completeness by reduction, the reduction should make solving $P_1$ "easy" if we could "easily" solve $P_2$.  Hence the reduction should take polynomial time.

A final simple observation that makes the reduction approach work for #P-completeness more or less as it does for NP-completeness is that composing two counting reductions yields a counting reduction.  Given a forest of known #P-complete problems, we can attach a new branch wherever we find it most convenient.